# Why doesn't the system retain an AVAudio player during playback?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

In most cases where you trigger an async system call and pass it a resource, the system keeps a strong reference to that resource so it will still be available.

`AVAudioPlayer` seems to be an exception.

The code

```
func playSound() {
  guard let soundFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"Shut your festering Gob", withExtension: "mp3") else {
    return
  }
  let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundFileURL)
  player?.play()
}
```

Doesn't work because the local variable `player` goes out of scope when the function returns and the audio player gets deallocated.

In contrast, scheduling a `Timer` retains the target of that timer as long as it runs. That seems the norm in Foundation classes.

It seems like the `AVFoundation` should take an owning reference to the `AVAudioPlayer` for the duration of the playback.

Does anybody know of a specific reason why `AVFoundation` **doesn't** retain the audio player during playback?

Comment: same goes for `AVPlayer`.

Answer (score 4):

The shoe is on the other foot. It is normal for a local variable to go out of scope, and out of existence, when the local context ends (execution reaches the end of the surrounding curly braces). Other behavior is what's unusual. You should therefore be asking why and how the timer is retained! That, as Sherlock Holmes would say, is the curious incident.

The answer is that when you *schedule* the timer you are specifically *asking* that it be retained (by the current runloop). That is just the special architecture of timers. However, it is usual to retain a reference to a timer anyway, in case you need to `invalidate` it.

Comment: But when I start an audio player playing I would expect AVFoundation to hold an owning reference to it  since it needs access to it in order to play it.

Comment: But unless you are _told_ that this happens, you _shouldn't_ expect it. Now, if you want to file an enhancement request at Apple, please do so; I encourage you to do so, because this catches a lot of beginners unawares, as you probably know. You could argue from the case of the speech recognizer, for example, where _nothing_ needs to be retained.